# bs4.element.ResultSet subsetting issue

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have cribbed a result set from some webpage source code using beautiful soup. I am then attempting to parse the text content of my result set. This is working fine, however I am also returning the header of the text, which I do not want.

Code is as so:

```
syn_divs = soup.findAll("div", {"class": "synopsis-container"})

for syn in syn_divs:

    if syn.text != "Synopsis":

        print syn.text
```

Result set content is as so:

```
<div class="synopsis-container">
<h2 class="section-title smaller">Synopsis</h2>
<p class="synopsis" itemprop="description">Two lovers - Muslim Ali (Adam Bakri) and Christian Nino (MarÃ­a Valverde) - have their marriage hopes thwarted by her Georgian parents and then an act carried out by Ali that forces him to flee a mountain village.Â  After reuniting, the couple are later separated by the Soviet invasion of Azerbaijan when Ali opts to take on the Red Army. Christopher Hampton (Dangerous Liaisons) adapts the 1937 novel.</p>
</div>
```

Returned string is as so:

```
Synopsis
Two lovers - Muslim Ali (Adam Bakri) and Christian Nino (María Valverde) - have their marriage hopes thwarted by her Georgian parents and then an act carried out by Ali that forces him to flee a mountain village.  After reuniting, the couple are later separated by the Soviet invasion of Azerbaijan when Ali opts to take on the Red Army. Christopher Hampton (Dangerous Liaisons) adapts the 1937 novel.
```

What I want is the film synopsis to be returned, but I do not want the header `Synopsis` also returned. What do I need to amend in my code?

Thanks

Comment: `soup.select('div.synopsis-container p')` should do it?

Comment: yes, that seems to have done the trick. thanks.

Comment: Or possibly... `soup.find_all('p', class_= 'synopsis')` maybe... you might want to self answer but I'm wondering if there's a dupe somewhere that shows how to use `.select` to select nested elements in BS4...